# How can I get the list of folders by full path in Google Drive

Tags: c#, rest, google-drive-api

Currently the GDrive APIs return files/folders complete info including a title, but there is no straight way to get the hierarchical path from root folder .
Is there any way to get the complete relative path except going recursively through its parents and generating full path ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get folder hierarchy with Google Drive API \[C# / .NET\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36052163/get-folder-hierarchy-with-google-drive-api-c-net)

Comment: No, you need to go recursively through its parents and generate a full path