# Drive API v3, C# - Folder Hierarchy

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I've got an app that communicates with Drive (specifically TeamDrives) and I need to pull a hierarchical folder structure within a given TeamDrive.

I can list my available TeamDrives then get the files (filter: folders mime type) within them but there doesn't seem to be any `parent` info to each folder so my structure is seemingly 'flat'.

I get that on Drive a folder is just a label and that 'sub-folders' could be shared in several places so I will cater for that but I just want to be able to create the directory tree on my app.

e.g. structure as I want to show it in my app:

- Team Drive Name

  - Main Folder

    - Sub Folder

My 'list' code:

```
var request = service.Files.List();
request.Corpora = "teamDrive";
request.IncludeTeamDriveItems = true;
request.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
request.OrderBy = "name";
request.PageSize = 100;

request.TeamDriveId = "[teamDriveId]";
request.Q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'";
```

This gives me for a given 'teamDriveId':

- Main Folder
- Sub Folder

`parent` on the `Sub Folder` result is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified which fields you want in the response, so you are getting the default which doesn't include parent information. Try adding `request.Fields = "*"`. I'm not familiar with the library you are using, so I might have the wrong syntax - please double check.

You might also find this useful [In Google Apps Script, how would I get all subfolders and all subsubfolders and all subsubsub folders etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55243153/in-google-apps-script-how-would-i-get-all-subfolders-and-all-subsubfolders-and)

Answer (score 0):

As pinoyyid suggested you need to add 'Fields' to your request.

`request.Fields = "name, id, parents";`

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder