# How to get list all sub folders name from parent folders in google sheet with apps script google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, subdirectory, google-drive-picker

How can i list all sub folders name from google drive into google sheets?

Here is the code, it's working but I cant put them in to google sheets.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93mcB.png)
In the place of logger i need replace the google sheet. Please help me out in this scenario?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55248127/7215091

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't use image for showing code. You can write code using Markdown formatting easily. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to use [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) to write the list of sub-folder names in Google Sheets, It will not work because your function require authorization when using DriveApp it will throw an error message `You do not have permission to call X service.`, the service requires user authorization and thus cannot be used in a custom function as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services).

You can write your sub-folder names in Google Sheets using [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet). But you need to specify the specific sheet and the cell where you want to write your data.

### Sample Code:

```
function findSubFolder(){
  var childFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxx').getFolders();
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();

  var childNames = [];
  while (childFolder.hasNext()) {
    var child = childFolder.next();
    Logger.log(child.getName());
    childNames.push([child.getName()]);
  }
  
 
 activeSheet.getRange(activeCell.getRow(),activeCell.getColumn(),childNames.length,1).setValues(childNames);
}
```

### What it does?

1. Get your active sheet using [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet) and the active cell using [Sheet.getActiveCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactivecell)
2. Get all your sub-folder names and add that to `childNames` array using [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

> Notice that when I pushed the child names I used `[sub-folder name]`, This is needed when we want use Range.setValues() which accepts a 2-d array where I want to have multiple rows.

3. Write the `childNames` array to the active sheet starting from the active cell. Using [Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) and [Range.setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

### Output:

[image]

---

If you want to write the sub-folder names on a single cell(in your active cell), you can replace

`activeSheet.getRange(activeCell.getRow(),activeCell.getColumn(),childNames.length,1).setValues(childNames);`

to

`activeCell.setValue(childNames.flat().toString());`

### Output:

[image]