# How to list all files recursively from google drive folder to spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

i am trying to the list all the files recursively from a google drive folder to a spreadsheet and sort the file listing by size ( Largest sized file should be on top ) . i am facing issues with the script

start function is giving the error - `ReferenceError: *****folder_id is not defined (Line 16)`

```
function start() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.clear();
    sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Date", "Size", "URL", "Download", "Description", "Type", "Folder", "Folder Slug"]);

    var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersById(FOLDER_ID);

    if (folder.hasNext()) {
        processFolder(folder);
    } else {
        Browser.msgBox('Folder not found!');
    }


    function processFolder(folder) {
        while (folder.hasNext()) {
            var f = folder.next();
            var contents = f.getFiles();
            addFilesToSheet(contents, f);
            var subFolder = f.getFolders();
            processFolder(subFolder);
        }
    }

    function addFilesToSheet(files, folder) {
        var data;
        var folderName = folder.getName();
        while (files.hasNext()) {
            var file = files.next();
            Logger.log(file.getName());

            sheet.appendRow([
      file.getName(),
      file.getDateCreated(),
      file.getSize(),
      file.getUrl(),
      "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=" + file.getId(),
      file.getDescription(),
      file.getMimeType(),
      folderName
    ]);
        }
    }

    
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55248127/7215091

Comment: @Cooper thanks for the input . On another note , does drive api has any option to get the size in terms of GB ( not bytes ) file.getSize() by default outputs size in bytes

Comment: Why don't you look it up?

Comment: i haven't been able to find it yet , i guess will ask a separate question for it then

Comment: This is the response for a get: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether a specific file type exist in Gdrive, you cannot use `If statement` but `file.hasnext()` function, below is the method to check only `spreadsheet` type and return the property as per your expectation, do take note that it will be meaningless action to get the `file size` of spreadsheet since it will be 0 byte due to store in Google database:

```
function fileType() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxx');
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getUrl());
    Logger.log(file.getName())
  }
}
```

I have performed the testing, the entire code work fine, except this part, by amended I will have all the log and sheet data updating :)

**From**

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersById(FOLDER_ID);

    if (folder.hasNext()) {
        processFolder(folder);
    } else {
        Browser.msgBox('Folder not found!');
    }
```

**To:**

```
var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxx');
    var folder = folders.getFolders();
    if (folder.hasNext()) {
        processFolder(folder);
    } else {
        Browser.msgBox('Folder not found!');
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it is easier to do with all files type, check my edited answer by using `getfiles`

Comment: But this doesn't work recursively , its only listing the files if they are directly present in the root of folderID passed to script

Comment: Are you trying to obtain entire file from all your folder??

Comment: You should use `.addUi` if you want to add custom menu https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus,  and `FOLDERID` is not a valid address, you should select specific folder for the one you want to check ie. `1xasddxxxx`, for the remaining part , I think it has many unnecessary call....and you need to workout on it based on the most simple method to get all file details and amend it...

Comment: I am obviously entering my folder id in its place  , i have replaced it with (FOLDER_ID) just for the purpose of this question

Comment: Check my edited answer, now it solve, accept if helping :)