# How to view files sorted by folders in Google Apps Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

I was watching [this video tutorial](https://youtu.be/Etl2aeQkg7k?list=PLPDoKe4e-Rtk6sNp3sv2SP5c6qkIe4lUM&t=13) about Google Apps Script, in the second #13 you can see that the project is sorted by folders, however, I can't see it like that, because it is shown as "backend/server.gs", I can't see the image of the folder and I can't close and open the folder.

I thought it was a very good utility and I would like to know if any of you know how to do it.

This is how it looks like in the video

[image: This is how it looks like in the video]

And this is how it shows to me

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try recursion...

Comment: What is that ??

Comment: Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55248127/7215091

Comment: It is not what I am searching for, what I need is a collapsible tree view in Google Apps Script editor for the project files like the first image in the question.

Comment: That's the kind of script you will need to create a tree view.  I've done it before.

Comment: I don't understand how SpreadsheetApp has relation with Google Apps Script Editor view, I've seen the link but it list the files in Google Drive to a Google Spreadsheet but I dont looking for that ... I want to see in the Google Apps Script Editor the folder icon and its files like I'd be in Visual Studio Code ... have a folder button when I click toggle the files inside that. But all of this in GAS Editor, I don't know if there is an configuration to do that.

Comment: Yes this particular recursive function was written for a specific purpose to do a tree view in a spreadsheet.  But if you wish to traverse a tree you will end up having to use a function that calls itself and that's what makes it recursive.  So while this particular script may not meet your needs it would be possible to strip out all of the spreadsheet stuff and end up with a bare bones recursive script that looks for files in a folder and when it gets through it starts looking for folders and when it finds one it calls itself and passes that folder as a parameter.  I'm running out of room.

Comment: I can show you and example of one.  Is that what you wish?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution and it was easier than it seems. I need to install a Google Chrome Extension called `AppsScript Color`.